# Image not centering

Tags: html, css

I am having a huge issue with my image not centring - I am wanting it to be in the centre of the `.container` div and not "left aligned".  I have tried `display:block; and margin: 0 auto;` with no change.

The CSS class's below have been called via the corresponding responsive css - I have not altered these files.

**HTML:**

```
 <!-- Logo Area -->
    <style type="text/css">#masthead { top: 37px;} </style>
    <div id="logoArea-wrap">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col span_2">

                <?php if($ct_options['ct_logo']) { ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><img class="site-logo" src="<?php echo $ct_options['ct_logo']; ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" /></a>
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><img class="site-logo" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/day-spa-logo.png" alt="WP Day Spa, a WordPress theme by Contempo" /></a>
                <?php } ?>                
            </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- //Logo Area -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can try is the following:

1. Change the inner `div` to have a class of `span_12` to give it a 100% width
2. On that same div, add a style for `text-align: center`
3. Add a fixed width to your image of `165px` (I used that size because that's what it is now).
4. Remove the `display: block` on the image

This should center the image

Comment: Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: sent you a tweet as its a bit complex for a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

I think the code have been override by bootstrap css, so try add !important, or make sure the code is loading after bootstrap css file:

```
.container {
    text-align: center !important; 
}
```

Or

```
#logoArea-wrap {
    text-align: center !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try is out, this is work for me.

```
    .container {
        width: 200px;
        height: 100px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }
    .container img{
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
```

or you can use this, [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n3cL236m/)